# Str object is not callable. Encode and decode message

Tags: python

I am new to python and programming in general. I was trying to encode and decode a message, but this mistake occurs. What does it mean? How to fix it?

```
 Def main():    
     Mes=input(" enter the message to encode").     
     Key= int(input(" enter the key").      
     Print(chr(ord(chr)+key) for chr in  mes)       
 main()
```

Comment: Why are naming your iterator variable `chr` while trying to use the built-in function `chr`? Use a different name such as `char` or `c`.

Comment: The correct syntax for defining a function is `def` rather than `Def`. Make sure you are using the correct capitalisation.

Comment: Don't lie. That code does not produce that error. You'd need to fix three or four syntax errors before you can even run that code at all.

Comment: this was posted from my phone, i didnt notice that mistakes, sorry. Why would i lie about a mistake and ask how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have written `for chr in  mes`, you have shadowed the built-in name `chr`. Now, `chr` refers to your string, not the python function. Replace it with something like:

```
chr(ord(mychar)+key) for mychar in  mes
```

Comment: thanks! now it works,but prints this: <generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0142FC00> instead of the encoded message

Comment: you need to put the expression you print inside `[]` if you want to make it a list. If an expression is inside parentheses, it creates a *generator* (look it up)

Answer (score 0):

This code is  my version of your program

```
def main():    
     Mes=input(" enter the message to encode ")     
     Key= int(input(" enter the key "))      
     for ch in  Mes:
          print(chr(ord(ch)+Key))        
main()
```

OUTPUT

```
 enter the message to encode me
 enter the key 2 
 o
 g
```